# Object data in template vue

Tags: vue.js

i want to get data username in object vue

```
gettAPI.get('/customers/', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}` } })
          .then(response => { 
            this.Profil = response.data.data,
            this.riz=this.Profil.user
            console.log(this.riz)

           
            console.log('ewkfjoiwpaejpo')
            
            console.log(this.Profil)

          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(`Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}`)
          })
```

[image]

i want to get data username in object vue  i want to get data username in object vue  i want to get data username in object vue

Comment: `i want to get data username in object vue` why did you repeat this statement four times? Your question is not clear. It looks like you already have the username in an object, it is in `[0].user.username` Why can you not bind that to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the console log, I think you should do

`this.riz=this.Profil[0].user` as `this.Profil` is an Array